# Is it possible to make an automatic search through the web to retrieve links?

Tags: javascript

Iḿ looking to make an automatic search through the web or websites to retrieve links. This is for the purpose of retrieving shared IP tv links in order to create a media library to watch Tṽ online using VLC. The point is, I don't know even what's the best solution, like a web page using script or a mini program... well I'm starting in the world of terminals and stuff, just installed xubuntu, so please... have some patience :D

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. You will have to write a [Web Crawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler).

JavaScript Node.JS Web Crawlers:

- https://scotch.io/tutorials/scraping-the-web-with-node-js
- http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-make-a-simple-web-crawler-in-javascript-and-node-js/

If you want to find specific links on the whole internet it is going to be time consuming, your crawlers needs to jump from site to site and follow each link it finds.

Comment: Ok, know I have somewhere to start... Thank you for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Besides Neils answer if you want a PHP library have look at the [PHP Simple DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net)

Some considerations ;

- First build your database. List of target Websites / URLs you want to scrape
- Using the PHP DOM parser ( Or any alternative ) create a script for each web page. This may be time consuming if you have multiple web pages with different layouts.
- Run the script and save your links into a Database
- Create a Cron job to run regularly and update your database.

[Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)
is also a solid alternative written in Python